# AdvancedDataGrid GroupingField

Tags: apache-flex

need my AdvancedDataGrid group by the name of the person, but I'm having trouble because the groupingField not accept "objectPeople.idPeople"

the name of the groupingField not accept "objectPeople.idPeople"?

GroupingField name="people.idPeople" <--error??

Comment: What is data provider for Advanced datagrid? give some code.. Anyway moropus gave nice explanation.

Answer (score 1):

That's because dot is not allowed in field handling.

**Explanation**.

Inside DataGrid addressing `groupingField` property from your item is held with square braces operator:

```
item[groupingField]
```

This addressing only supports one level. E.g. if you've got object inside object, you cannot address properties of the second one with square braces in first:

```
var outer:Object = new Object();
var inner:Object = new Object();
outer["property"] = inner;
inner["value"] = 0;
trace(outer["property.value"]); // runtime error
trace(outer.property.value); // traces 0

outer["property.value"] = 1; // creates property "property.value" in outer
trace(outer["property.value"]); // traces 1
trace(outer.property.value); // still traces 0
```

**Answer.**

If you have `idPeople` inside your item, you should specify `groupingField="idPeople"`.

If you have `objectPeople` with `idPeople` property inside your item, you should (for instance) write a getter in your item to avoid multiple levels and specify its name in groupinf field property - `groupingField="idPeople"`:

```
public function get idPeople():Number
{
    return objectPeople.idPeople;
}

// ...
trace(item["idPeople"]); // works now
```